# How can you fetch more than 10,000 rows from Google Analytics using google2pandas

Tags: python-3.x, google-analytics

Trying to understand how i can fetch more than 10K rows from Google Analytics using Google2Pandas. I have this:

```
from google2pandas import *

conn = GoogleAnalyticsQuery(secrets='./ga-creds/client_secrets.json', token_file_name='./ga-creds/analytics.dat')

query = {\
'ids' : '56611942',
'metrics' : 'pageviews',
'dimensions' : ['date', 'pagePath','browser','city','country'],
'start_date' : '2013-01-01',
'end_date':'2017-10-01',
'max_results' : 10
}

df, metadata = conn.execute_query(**query)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here: http://www.ryanpraski.com/google-analytics-sheets-add-on-unsampled-data-more-than-10000-rows/

I use this solution and worked perfectly. Also if you want a even better implementation i can send you a code i use today based on threads and other stuff that will let you exploit the API.